# Summarize full name to short name.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've a problem in my website (built with **PHP** script), 
I want to to summarize full name student ex: **"Ahmad Najib Fuadi"** from database to short name **"A.N. Fuadi"** in my website:

I already have database like this :

```
|    FNAME     |   LNAME  |
|--------------|----------|
|  Ahmad Najib |   Fuadi  |
```

I have tried with code like this:

```
 <tbody>
<?php if($query):foreach($query as $post):?>    
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $post->FNAME; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $post->LNAME ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
</tbody>
```

**I got no idea to short First Name (FNAME)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a regex?

```
<tbody>
<?php if($query): foreach($query as $post): ?>    
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo preg_replace('/(.)[^\s]+\s?/', '${1}.', strtoupper($post->FNAME)); ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $post->LNAME; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modify your code check and confirm

```
<?php if($query):foreach($query as $post):?>    
<tr>
    <td class="center">
    <?php 
    $fname = $post->FNAME;
            $firstName = getAbrName($fname);  /// call function with pass first name
    //$firstName = substr($fname,0,1).'.';
    //if(strpos($fname,' ')){
    //  $firstName .= substr($fname,(strpos($fname,' ')+1),1).'.';
    //}
    echo $firstName;
    ?>
    </td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $post->LNAME;?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php function getAbrName($name = ''){
       $nameArray = explode(' ',$name);
    $returnName = '';
    if(is_array($nameArray)){
        foreach($nameArray as $value){
            $returnName .= substr($value,0,1).'.';
        }
    }
    return $returnName;
}
?>
```

Comment: If the FNAME has more than two parts , this will only consider the first two parts and will disregard from the 3rd part

Comment: I have updated the code please check this will work for unlimited number of spaces in first name

Answer (score 2):

Try my function `getShortName`

```
function getShortName($fname, $lname){
    $name = '';
    foreach(explode(' ',  $fname) as $fn)
        $name .= strtoupper($fn[0]) . '. ';

    $name .= ucfirst($lname);
    return $name;
}
```

Testing Data:

```
$names = array(
        array('fname' => 'Ahmad', 'lname' => 'Fuadi'),
        array('fname' => 'Ahmad Najib', 'lname' => 'Fuadi'),
        array('fname' => 'Ahmad najib mama', 'lname' => 'Fuadi'),
        array('fname' => 'ahmad baba Mama', 'lname' => 'Fuadi'),
        array('fname' => 'allen iverson', 'lname' => 'chak')
    );

foreach($names as $n)
    print(getShortName($n['fname'], $n['lname']) . "<br />");
```

Testing Result:

```
A. Fuadi
A. N. Fuadi
A. N. M. Fuadi
A. B. M. Fuadi
A. I. Chak
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$first = "Ahmad Najib";//fetch real first name from the database
$last = "Fuadi";//fetch real name from the database
$result = rtrim(preg_replace('#([^ ])[^ ]* *#i', '$1. ', $first)," ");
$result = "$result $last";
echo "$result";//or do something else with the shorter name
```

The method works quite robust, for instance double spaces (`"  "`) are interpreted as simply one space, etc.

You can test this code [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

---

Thus when merging this method with your own code, one gets:

```
<tbody>
<?php if($query):foreach($query as $post):?>    
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php
        $first = $post->FNAME;
        $result = rtrim(preg_replace('#([^ ])[^ ]*[ ]*#i', '$1. ', $first)," ");
        echo $result;
        ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $post->LNAME ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below .
Irrespective of how many parts FNAME is made up of , this will only consider maximum of first two parts from the left .

```
SELECT

CONCAT
(
    SUBSTR( FNAME ,1 ,1 ) ,'.'

    ,IF
    (
         LOCATE( ' ' ,FNAME ) > 0
        ,CONCAT( SUBSTR( FNAME FROM ( 1 + LOCATE( ' ' ,FNAME ) ) FOR 1 ) ,'.' )
        ,''
    )

    ,' '

    ,LNAME
) AS short_name

FROM table_name
```

So :
`Ahmad` , `Fuadi` results : `A. Fuadi`
`Ahmad Najib` , `Fuadi` results : `A.N. Fuadi`
`Ahmad Najib Mahmood` , `Fuadi` also results : `A.N. Fuadi`

Comment: What happens if one has only one first name, or more than two, etc.?